# Auto filter method of range class failed with Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set rmdvsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(11)

    rmdvsheet.Range("A1:K103").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
        "D7u L462-L494 17MY"
```

Here on 2nd line i am geting an error saying "Auto filter method of range class failed".

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is with the range you've defined.  The autofilter only wants referral to the header row.  If you sub this into your code, it should work the way you expect (the only change is in the range from `K103` to `K1"`):

```
rmdvsheet.Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="D7u L462-L494 17MY"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you are turned to the right sheet and no other syntax error. It's because maybe in the original sheet, it is already autofiltered. Like in the following picture. To solve this, just click the filter button to return to the unfilter status.
[image: 1]

Comment: @mattsnider *`To solve this, just click the filter button`*. You think this *does not really answer the question*?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct worksheet.

Make sure the data in the sheet cells have no double quotes.  Like:

[image: see it]

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue is that you need to convert your Worksheet from Table to Range.
(I do this for all my macros to be safe).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).