# How to filter an Excel Table with Column Name & Criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, excel-tables

I'm trying to run a macro that will pull data from a Table in Excel, when the Table might initially be filtered.

The code should:

1. Clear the Table filter
2. Apply a filter to the Column Heading: "STATUS" Criteria1:= "O"
3. Then run the rest of the code.

I want to use the Column Header name: "STATUS", because the Table has changed a few times, and the Index could also change.

Through various researches, and attempts, I think I have the correct line that will clear the filter WITHOUT removing filters from the table.
However, I am now getting the: "AutoFilter method of Range class failed" on Step 2:

```
Sub OpenPOs()
    
Dim wbInventory As Workbook
Set wbInventory = Workbooks("IWI Inventory MASTER Report.xlsb")
    
   With wbInventory
      With wsPOTracker 'This is a Code name for worksheet within the workbook
                
        'Clear the Table Filter
         If Not .ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
               
         'Apply Table Filter to the Column: "STATUS" Criteria = "O"
         .ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("STATUS").Range.AutoFilter , Criteria1:="O" '<Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed

 'Rest of the code
```

Links I've tried to research/copy from:

[Clear filter from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197641/clear-filter-from-table)

[Auto filter method of range class failed with Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941764/auto-filter-method-of-range-class-failed-with-criteria)

[Auto filter method of range class failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703538/auto-filter-method-of-range-class-failed)

Comment: `With wsPOTracker` is missing the `.` so it's not scoped to `wbInventory`. Is your code in "IWI Inventory MASTER Report.xlsb", or another workbook?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, the code is within `wbInventory`.   

I just tried to add `With .wsPOTracker`, and the autotext doesn't populate `wsPOTracker` after the `.`  I added it manually, and got an Error: 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.
`wsPOTracker` is a Code name

Comment: If the code is in that same workbook then you can use `With ThisWorkbook` in place of `With wbInventory`  (though you don't even need that, since you can just refer to `wsPOTracker` directly)

Comment: I switched that, but I still get the error when trying to autofilter for the Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim lo As ListObject
    
Set lo = wsPOTracker.ListObjects("Table1") 'reference the listobject/table
    
If Not lo.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=lo.ListColumns("STATUS").Index, Criteria1:="O"
```

Comment: that worked! So, now I'm curious, I use the `with wsPOTracker`, to make sure the right worksheet is being used throughout the lengthy macro.  I didn't know I needed to `Dim / Set` a `.ListObjects` if it was already within the worksheet I stated?

Comment: You don't *need* to, but it's generally easier to manage your code if you're not writing `.ListObjects("Table1")` multiple times.  For example if you change the table name, you only have one place to edit your code when using `lo` vs. potentially many places otherwise.  You may still want to keep the `With wsPOTracker` for the rest of your code though...